# Flicker on render when using glass shader

Tags: rendering

I have a render that is using multiple glass doors on a cabinet. I am getting flickering ie light levels varying from frame to frame. I have other shelves on the unit that don't have any glass in front of them and they are not flickering. My suspicion is that it may have something to do with cycles renderer or the glass BSDF. I have attached my settings for the renderer.

[image]

Comment: How many glass doors are there and what _Max Bounces_ settings do you have under _Light Paths_?

Comment: also would be great to see some frames from the render to see what kind of flickering is going on. 
the important settings would be under the light paths category

Comment: Why not share a screenshot or a [.gif](https://www.screentogif.com/) of the problem so everyone could understand what's going on instantly at a single glance?

Answer (score -1):

If the glass in the cabinets is a plane (2d) that might make it do something wierd.
also you could try using principled bsdf with transmission on.